# Magento doesn't show telephone number of guest checkout user (onepage checkout)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

Magento won't save telephone numbers for guest customers in onepage checkout. Telephone number is a mandatory field on onepage checkout form as shown in the image

[image]

but in adminpanel in order details it doesn't show the telephone number as shown in the following image

[image]

I did managed to solve the issue but that was about a year ago and don't remember how I did it. Google is no help at least for me in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the shipping.phtml.

Replace the existing Telephone field using the below code

```
<div class="field">
 <label for="shipping:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
  <input type="text" name="shipping[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="shipping:telephone" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
      </div>
           </div>
```